# orientdb log while indexing odd number of items and complete percentage

Tags: indexing, progress, graph-databases, orientdb

While indexing a property, of a superclass, (this superclass has some 150 vertex subtypes) I get this as log:

```
{db=some.db} --> 1,95% progress, 34.909 indexed so far (3.490 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> 2,84% progress, 50.789 indexed so far (1.588 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> 3,55% progress, 63.589 indexed so far (1.280 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> 4,24% progress, 75.827 indexed so far (1.223 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> 10,07% progress, 180.260 indexed so far (10.443 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> 327,57% progress, 5.862.702 indexed so far (568.244 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> 335437,16% progress, 6.003.580.546 indexed so far (599.771.784 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> 85871952,00% progress, 1.536.917.340.206 indexed so far (153.091.375.966 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> 175865757696,00% progress, 3.147.606.712.362.970 indexed so far (314.606.979.502.276 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> 175865757696,00% progress, 3.147.606.712.385.221 indexed so far (2.225 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> 175865757696,00% progress, 3.147.606.712.407.636 indexed so far (2.241 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> -278094233468928,00% progress, -4.977.269.306.657.122.609 indexed so far (-498.041.691.336.953.024 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> -278094233468928,00% progress, -4.977.269.306.657.110.370 indexed so far (1.223 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> -75741320445952,00% progress, -1.355.601.418.262.482.509 indexed so far (362.166.788.839.462.786 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> -75741320445952,00% progress, -1.355.601.418.262.473.293 indexed so far (921 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> -75741320445952,00% progress, -1.355.601.418.262.461.945 indexed so far (1.134 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> -75741320445952,00% progress, -1.355.601.418.262.452.365 indexed so far (958 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> -75741320445952,00% progress, -1.355.601.418.262.443.675 indexed so far (869 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> -75741320445952,00% progress, -1.355.601.418.262.429.600 indexed so far (1.407 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> -75741320445952,00% progress, -1.355.601.418.262.415.268 indexed so far (1.433 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> -181188882857984,00% progress, -3.242.878.618.489.543.499 indexed so far (-188.727.720.022.712.823 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> 513284360896512,00% progress, 9.186.650.528.658.242.427 indexed so far (-601.721.492.656.176.569 items/sec) 
{db=some.db} --> 513284360896512,00% progress, 9.186.650.528.658.254.543 indexed so far (1.211 items/sec)
```

This strikes me as odd, but particularly in doubt as to whether something is going wrong. Since my database is getting pretty large, it is nearly impossible to check all records. So, should I ignore this?

Update:

```
{db=some.db} - Rebuilding index some.db.ontology.uid (estimated 1791173 items)... [OIndexRebuildOutputListener]
{db=some.db} --> 3,10% progress, 55.472 indexed so far (5.547 items/sec) [OIndexRebuildOutputListener]
{db=some.db} --> 1309,24% progress, 23.450.831 indexed so far (2.339.535 items/sec) [OIndexRebuildOutputListener]
{db=some.db} --> 43932196864,00% progress, 786.901.678.087.007 indexed so far(78.690.165.463.617 items/sec) [OIndexRebuildOutputListener]
```

Comment: This is a only problem on output. Could you report here 5 lines before the first one you posted? There are precious information about the number of elements to index

Comment: @Lvca only 1.7 million. The 'Update' is all I see in the stdout. Also, especially relevant for larger indices, the database freezes on indexing

Comment: Dunno why the counter is messy, how can I reproduce it?